# Share/collaborate a .NET application via RDP?

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, terminal-services, desktop-sharing

Can someone point me to examples/documentation showing me how share a single C# .net 3.5 based application via RDP / Desktop Sharing?

I found this blog post, but am not sure where to go from here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2007/03/08/windows-desktop-sharing-api.aspx

I'm running on Windows 7, but don't want to share the entire desktop.  Just the specific application I am writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with [this sample C# application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2007/03/23/writing-a-desktop-sharing-application.aspx) and use the [`IRDPSRAPIApplicationFilter` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373267%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to set which application should be shared.

I haven't tried this yet, but my guess is that you would set `IRDPSRAPIApplicationFilter.Enabled = true` and then
set `Shared = true` for one of the `IRDPSRAPIApplication` objects in the
`IRDPSRAPIApplicationFilter.Applications` collection, or for one of the
`IRDPSRAPIWindow` objects in the `IRDPSRAPIApplicationFilter.Windows` collection.